# How to save a file that already exists?

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I'm going to launch a code editor for people to create bots to disagree, it's almost all ready, but what I need help is when saving the file, I created a function that saves but when the file already exists the person have to replace, then I created a String called currentFile that will store the path of the selected file, then how do I make it just replace the text inside the file without needing to replace the file or open the save menu?

```
String currentFile = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EXAMPLE\\FILE.js";

SaveFileDialog sfd = default(SaveFileDialog);
            if (fctb_code.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                //sfd.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
                //sfd.DefaultExt = "html";

                sfd.ShowDialog();


                string location = currentFile;
                string sourcecode = fctb_code.Text;
                location = sfd.FileName;
                if (!object.ReferenceEquals(sfd.FileName, ""))
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(location, false))
                    {
                        writer.Write(sourcecode);
                        writer.Dispose();
                    }
                }
```

And I want that when the file exists it just replaces the text inside the file, but when it doesn't exist it saves the file as a new one and opens SaveFileDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code you have posted underneath `sfd.ShowDialog();` can be replaced with one simple command (and an if statement)

```
if (sfd.FileName != "")
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(currentFile, fctb_code.Text);
}
```

No need for Streams and StreamWriters. No obtuse `if` logic.

To quote [the documentation for File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-6.0), this will do overwriting for you:

> Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

Comment: The caveat here is that `File.WriteAllText` requires that the entire text fits into memory, whereas streams allow you to write to a file with minimal memory usage. In this case, however, the data is in memory already and `WriteAllText` is perfect.